# Derivation of the Stochastic Vol PDE

Tags: option-pricing, implied-volatility, stochastic-calculus

I'm trying to follow the derivation of the stochastic vol pde for an option price - as given in Gatheral (The vol surface), Wilmott on Quant Finance and many other places. As usual one starts off with a portfolio $\Pi = C + \Delta S + \Delta_1 V$, from which we want to derive a PDE which the option price $C(t,S,\sigma)$ satisfies. Apply Ito's formula, and choosing the hedge ratios appropriately we can make this portfolio riskless. After some algebra we end up with something like

$$g(S, C,C_t, C_S, C_{SS}, C_\sigma, C_{\sigma,s})=g(S,V,V_t, V_S, V_{SS}, V_\sigma, V_{\sigma,s})$$

i.e. a relationship $g$ between the derivatives of $V$ and $C$ (in particular I'm referring to the first equation on page 6 [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/ctff03/Gatheral.1.pdf)).  Now this is the part I don't understand, right under that equation the author says something along the lines, "Since the left hand side is a function of $C$ only and the right hand side is a function of $V$ only, the only way the equality can be true is if both sides equal to some function $f$ of the independent variables $S$, $\sigma$ and $t$". Can someone explain why this is so exactly?

And also why without loss of generality can we assume this function takes the form $f(t,S,\sigma)=\alpha-\phi \beta \sqrt{\sigma}$?

The complete derivation can be found [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/ctff03/Gatheral.1.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. So we have the identity $$g(S,\sigma, t, C,C_t,C_S,...)=g(S, t,\sigma, V,V_t,V_S,...)$$
   where 
   $S$, $\sigma$, and $t$ are independent variables and $V=V(S,\sigma,t)$, $C=C(S,\sigma,t)$ are some unknown functions. But we can also treat the above identity formally 
   and assume that the *functions* $C,C_t,C_S,...,V,V_t,V_S,... $ are themselves independent *parameters* or *variables*. Now, if we fix all variables except for $C$ and compute the partial derivative $\partial g/\partial C$ we will find that
   $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial C}=0$$
   for all values of $S,\sigma, t,C_t,C_S,...,V,V_t,V_S,...$ since the *right-hand side* of the identity does not depend on $C$. This imples that $g$ is constant with respect to $C$. Similarly, one can get that
   $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial V}=0$$
   since the *left-hand side* of the identity does not depend on $V$. Hence, $g$ is constant with respect to $V$ as well.

   We can repeat this argument for $C_t,C_S,...,V_t,V_S,... $, which would imply that $g$
   does not depend on any of those formal variables. However, we cannot apply the same argument to any of the variables $S$, $\sigma$ or $t$, since *both* sides of the identity depend on each of the them. In other words,
   $$ g(S,\sigma, t, C,C_t,C_S,...)=g(S, t,\sigma, V,V_t,V_S,...)=f(S,\sigma, t)$$
   for some function $f=f(S,\sigma, t)$. The above argument is not dissimilar to the standard trick of  [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations) which is used to solve simple partial differential equations.
2. Now, we can simply express the unknown function $f$ in terms of another arbitrary function $\phi=\phi(S,\sigma, t)$:
   $$f= -(\alpha-\phi\beta).$$
   We do not know the function $\phi$ explicitly, of course. However, it is just slightly more convenient to deal with $\phi$ rather than $f$, and, besides, the former can be interpreted  as the 'market price of risk'.

Comment: Great answer, do you have a good reference/intuition as to why $\phi$ is interpreted as the market price of risk?  Is this the same idea of market price of risk in BS: $\frac{\mu - r}{\sigma}$?